# Merge json objects that with the same value of property c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, .net-core

How to combine JSON objects in the same response that has the same key and value. like if I've two objects that have the same language: Python I want to combine them and List the remaining data under this language Python I don't want it being repeated

```
[
  [
    {
      "language": "Python",
      "id": 319029846,
      "full_Name": "beurtschipper/Depix",
      "name": "Depix"
    },
    {
      "language": "Python",
      "id": 319169382,
      "full_Name": "benwilber/boltstream",
      "name": "boltstream"
    },
    {
      "language": "Python",
      "id": 316899719,
      "full_Name": "r0ysue/r0capture",
      "name": "r0capture"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "language": "YARA",
      "id": 318029147,
      "full_Name": "fireeye/red_team_tool_countermeasures",
      "name": "red_team_tool_countermeasures"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "language": "TypeScript",
      "id": 313443335,
      "full_Name": "pmndrs/valtio",
      "name": "valtio"
    }
  ]
]
```

what the form I want is

```
[
  [
    {
      "language": "Python",
      "id": [319029846, 319169382, 316899719],
      "full_Name": ["beurtschipper/Depix", "benwilber/boltstream", "r0ysue/r0capture"],
      "name": ["Depix", "boltstream", "r0capture"]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "language": "YARA",
      "id": 318029147,
      "full_Name": "fireeye/red_team_tool_countermeasures",
      "name": "red_team_tool_countermeasures"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "language": "TypeScript",
      "id": 313443335,
      "full_Name": "pmndrs/valtio",
      "name": "valtio"
    }
  ]
]
```

And this is the code i'm using

```
    public class Items
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public  string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("full_name")]
        public string Full_Name { get; set; }
        public string total_count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("items")]
        public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
    }


        Root jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(readerResult);
        var result = jObj2.Items.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Language,
            x.Id,
            x.Full_Name,
            x.Name
        }).GroupBy(x => x.Language).ToArray();
        return new JsonResult(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy` is a good place to start. Once you have the groups, you need to select the individual properties of each group into a new list:

```
var result = jObj2.Items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Language)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Language = group.Key,
        Ids = group.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(),
        FullNames = group.Select(x => x.Full_Name).ToList(),
        Names = group.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Oh sir I feel ashamed of how easy it is unless I've tried to put those ids, names..etc to list `Ids = group.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(),`  but I ran into that's they aren't a list and I didn't even though that I should the GroupBy before the Select and now I kinda know how GroupBy is actually working.
 if you don't mind I would ask another question .. is that thing to know comes with experience or I didn't learn well?
and sure Thank you very much I appreciate your help.

Comment: The more often you use Linq, the easier you will find these kinds of tasks